# C Program doesn't end after giving the correct output

Tags: c, while-loop

So I'm trying to do a program that reads a sequence of numbers separated by spaces and new lines. The output should be the same sequence, but erasing unnecessary zeros(The sequence of charachters 'EOF' ends the program). Per example

1. 01492 102934 should come out as 1492 102934
2. 9312 0 01923 should come out as 9312 0 1923
3. 0001249 0000 should come out as 1249 0

Well I've achieved that purpose but have come across a roadblock. The program doesn't exit unless I type the EOF sequence. Maybe it's because I have a while(1) running that gives an infinite loop. But when I try to delete it the program doesn't even print at all. I'm still learning this is for a school project.
Any help would be apreciated!

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
char c;
int i=0;
while(1){
    c=getchar();
    if (i==0){
        if(c=='0'){
            while (c=='0'){
            c=getchar();
            }
        }
        printf("%c",c);
        i=i+1;
    }
    else if (c==' '){
        printf("%c",c);
        c=getchar();
        if(c=='0'){
            while (c=='0'){
            c=getchar();
            }
        }
        printf("%c",c);
    }
    else if (c=='E'){
        c=getchar();
        if (c=='O'){
            c=getchar();
            if(c=='F'){
                printf("\n");
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        printf("%c",c);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You can use `break;` to exit a while loop.

Comment: @Francisco Cunha is the eof part necessary for you? I can think of a better way to implement this.

Comment: @PiRocks but how do I make sure the `break;` only takes action after the program has read and printe dthe whole input?

Comment: What do you mean by whole input?

Comment: @hitter It is. The program should end if one of two things happen: the'EOF' sequence or reading and printing the whole input

Comment: @PiRocks Per example: if the input is 91240 89142 18249; how do i make sure the `break;` only takes effect after reading and printing the last 9?

Comment: So if you read a newline you want the program to exit?

Comment: A conceptual problem is that a user may type "E12". That will at least throw away the `1`. (Of course such entry should still be rejected as invalid input.) Did you not try to use one of the functions that reads an entire line, rather than one character at a time?

Comment: @PiRocks The new lines should also be included in the output. But the problem is there should only be one input (it may contain spaces and newlines though). As of right now, after printing a sequence, the program just asks for a new input. It only stops if it reads the 'EOF' sequence.

Comment: @usr2564301 I hadn't thought aout that since I have to make changes in each line. How do I delete the unnecessary 0's if i read entire lines? Because otherwise that would be a great solution to the current problem

Comment: @hitter Thanks i really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There has to be some way to tell the program to exit.
With this, the program will exit on the letter `x` or two consecutive newlines or entering `END`.
`getchar` will return `EOF` when there is nothing left to read from a file. That can be simulated from `stdin` ( the keyboard) with `ctrl + z` on Windows or `ctrl + d` on Linux.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ( void) {
    char done[4] = "";
    int c = 0;
    int prior = 0;
    int reading = 0;
    int zero = 1;

    while ( EOF != ( c = getchar ( )) && 'x' != c) {
        if ( '\n' == c && '\n' == prior) {
            break;
        }
        if ( c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
            reading = 1;
            if ( '0' != c) {
                zero = 0;
            }
            if ( ! zero) {
                putchar ( c);
            }
        }
        else {
            if ( reading) {
                if ( zero) {
                    putchar ( '0');
                }
                if ( ' ' == c || '\n' == c) {
                    putchar ( c);
                }
                else {
                    putchar ( ' ');
                }
            }
            reading = 0;
            zero = 1;
        }
        prior = c;

        done[0] = done[1];
        done[1] = done[2];
        done[2] = c;
        done[3] = 0;
        if ( 0 == strcmp ( done, "END")) {
            break;
        }
    }
    putchar ( '\n');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok so this was the best answer so far. Since i can now actually exit the program and get the correct output. One problem tho is that one of the automatic tests provided by the school gives out the error : `\ No newline at end of file` . I've tried scanning your code to try and figure out where it might be but I can't seem to find it.  Any idea?

Comment: It means every output should be ended with a `\n`.

Answer (score 5):

The important stuff:

```
int c; // IMPORTANT, cannot be char
while (1) {
    c = getchar();
    if (c == EOF) break; // exit loop
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate why? I've tried implementing this but it just broke the entire program, giving the incorrect output, and not really solving the old problem.

Comment: `int` is VERY IMPORTANT because with `char` you cannot distinguish between a valid character and the `EOF` signal. Lets assume 8 bits... `getchar()` returns positive values for valid characters (0 to 255) or `EOF` (a negative value, usually `-1`) for signal. When converting this `int` value/signal to `char` either the valid character 255 gets converted to `-1` or the signal `-1` gets converted to character `255` (depending on the signedness of `char` in your implementation).

Comment: @pmg I don't quite understand how that will fix the problem. I can understand what you are saying, but I don't think that will be of much help

Comment: `while ( EOF != ( c = getchar ())) {....}`. No `break` needed.

Comment: @FranciscoCunha If one doesn't take computer architecture course, it is genuinely hard to grasp its logic.

Comment: @FranciscoCunha It's actually pretty simple: the value of `EOF` doesn't fit into a `char`.  And it's deliberately designed that way because otherwise there'd be no way to distinguish the value of `EOF` from the value of a valid `char`.  In hex notation, `char` values might be from `0x00` to `0xFF`, using 8 bit 'char` values.  A 32-bit `int` representation of `EOF` might be `0xFFFFFFFF`.  If you assign that 32-bit `EOF` value to a `char`, it will be truncated to `0xFF`, which is a valid `char` value.

Answer (score 1):

1. `getchar()` returns an int, not a char. If it only returned a char, there would be no way for it to return a value that indicates end of file, since all char values are valid and can’t be used for another purpose.

   A motivating example in decimal system may be: *A function checks the temperature returns a two-digit number. Any temperature between 0 and 99 is valid. How do you report errors when the thermometer is disconnected? You have to return a number with more digits, and use a special value like `UNPLUGGED = 100`*.

   But int is a wider type: it has many more values than char, and the “extra” values can be used to indicate some special condition that means “hey, this is not a valid character, but something else I had to tell you”.
2. `getchar()` returns the `EOF` constant upon failure (any failure), for example if no more input is available. There’s nothing sensible you can do even if the reason for the failure other than end of input. You should end processing at the first EOF.

Thus, change the type of `c` to int, and every time you call `getchar()`, you must check that its value is not EOF, and `return` when you encounter it.

The nested structure of your loops means that EOF checking has to be repeated all over the place. There are other ways to structure the code to keep this check in one place, but, admittedly, the nested loops have at least the potential to exploit the branch predictor, whereas a single `getchar` followed by a state-machine style `switch` statement will make it perform potentially worse. None of this matters in a simple homework problem, but it’s something to keep in mind. In any case, performance has to be benchmarked - no other way around it.

Comment: `EOF` is not a character. To augment your example it's like: 1) "Q: what's the temp?"; "A: 42" or 2) "Q: what's the temp?"; "A: yellow"

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, I think it does what you requested:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int getLine(char *prmpt, char *buff, size_t sz) {
    int ch, extra;

    // Get line with buffer overrun protection.
    if (prmpt != NULL) {
        printf("%s", prmpt);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    if (fgets(buff, sz, stdin) == NULL)
        return -2;
    // If it was too long, there'll be no newline. In that case, we flush
    // to end of line so that excess doesn't affect the next call.
    if (buff[strlen(buff) - 1] != '\n') {
        extra = 0;
        while (((ch = getchar()) != '\n') && (ch != EOF))
            extra = 1;
        return (extra == 1) ? -1 : 0;
    }
    // Otherwise remove newline and give string back to caller.
    buff[strlen(buff) - 1] = '\0';
    return 0;
}

int* convert2numbers(char* arr, int size) {
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;

    char token[100];
    int* numbers;
    int last_space = 0;
    int index = 1;
    int amount = 1;
    // Count the amount of tokens.

    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        if (arr[i] == ' ') {
            ++amount;
        }
    }
    numbers = (int *)malloc(amount * sizeof(int));
    numbers[0] = amount;

    for (j = 0; j <= size; ++j) {
        if (arr[j] == ' ' || arr[j] == '\0') {

            // Copy token from input string.
            for (k = 0; k < j; ++k) {
                token[k] = arr[k + last_space];
            }
            token[j] = '\0';
            numbers[index] = atoi(token);
            // Clear the token and continue.
            memset(token, '\0', sizeof(token));
            last_space = j;
            ++index;
        }
    }
    return numbers;
}

int main(void) {
    int i;
    int size;
    int* numbers;
    int amount;
    char input[100];
    char help[] = "Numbers> ";

    printf("Input numbers below or press enter to exit!\n");
    while (1) {
        getLine(help, input, sizeof(input));
        // If input is empty exit.
        if (input[0] == '\0') {
            break;
        }
        size = strlen(input);
        numbers = convert2numbers(input, size);
        amount = numbers[0];
        for (i = 1; i < amount + 1; ++i) {
            printf("%d ", numbers[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When run with these inputs this code outputs:

```
Input numbers below or press enter to exit!
Numbers> 01492 102934
1492 102934
Numbers> 9312 0 01923
9312 0 1923
Numbers> 0001249 0000
1249 0
```

Also if you press `enter` in console, it exits, as to escape the `while(1)` loop, easily.

Comment: @Francisco Cunha Sry this code took me way longer than expected. I hope you like it. It features a safe way to parse numbers as strings from console.
You could copy paste these functions in the future ;)

Comment: It seems fine. But the problem is the program should only ask the user once for the input. In your example, the program will keep asking for new inputs until I press the enter key twice if I'm not mistaken. Additionally there are a lot of parts in your code that seem unnecessary/too long. I think the program could be done with no more than 30/40 lines of code, I just don't understand how.

Comment: I've decided to try @user3121023 's answer, it is closer to the solution. The only problem is minor so if I can figure out which part of the code is producing that, I think it would be solved

Comment: @FranciscoCunha We are talking about C, where most things are done manually.
So I don't think you could get a shorter version than the accepted answer.
Other than that, I understand you wanted to keep getting inputs until you've read an EOF character, so yeah if you give an empty sequence by pressing enter, my code exits, as expected.

Comment: @FranciscoCunha If you want to do string parsing which is more common than character parsing, use my getline, its a really safe function, with useful error codes.

Comment: The program should only ask for one input, I'm sorry If i didn't mention that. But if the EOF character is read then it ends prematurely. Otherwise it reads the entire input, prints the desired output and then ends the program.

Comment: @FranciscoCunha Oh ok, don't worry if you give it EOF, it will stop.